# 04 Outback Coolant Reservoir Overflowing

Tags: subaru, overheating

I’ve got an 04 Outback that I am nearly at my wits end with. The coolant reservoir is overflowing and my car overheats if I dont continually replace the coolant. I’ve been dealing with it over heating for about a year now and have already fixed quite a few things. Here is everything that’s been done:

-New head gaskets
-New water pump
-New radiator cap (x2)
-New thermostat (x2) 
-Fans running just fine
-Heater core just fine 
-Multiple coolant flushes (the lastest was about three weeks ago - and have lost about 1.5 quarts since then.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have found quite a few screwed up “fixes” from the last guy who owned it, but so far I’m out of options to explain this one.

Comment: Has the system been “bled” or “burped” correctly - some cars needed the front raising in the air four feet compared to the rear to get rid of some airlocks...

Comment: I’ve bled it, but never with the front raised - I ‘ll look into that!